# How to get total number of ids appearing in response in JMeter?

Tags: count, jmeter, request, response

The json response body is:

```html
{
  "status": 11111,
  "data": {
    "mylist": 
    {
      "1": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "tId": 11
        }],
    
      "2": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "tId": 12
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "tId": 12
  
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "tId": 13,
        }
      ]
}
```

Here, I want to get the count of ids present **within "2"** and not from "1". In above example I want to get idcount=3.

Comment: Post a valid JSON

Comment: posted, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) as a child of the request which returns the above response
2. Configure it as follows:

   [image]

   Textual version of the [JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) expression just in case: `$.data.mylist.2.*.id`
3. You will get the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) (can be visualized using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)):

   [image]

   ```
   id_1=2
   id_2=3
   id_3=4
   id_matchNr=3
   ```

   so you will be able to refer this `3` as `${id_matchNr}` where required